# Socket.IO Connection Not working on University Wifi

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have created an chat app using Socket.IO . It works fine on my home internet. But whenever I am at my university and connected to versity wifi internet, I can't get connected at all. Its facing 'net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT' error.

Here is the url: demo.codesamplez.com/ultrachat/demo.html (You will may get it OK, as I do on home)

I guess, this might be some kind of firewall issue or something?

Does anybody has any clue how to go forward for solving this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is possible that the university is using an http proxy that doesn't support webSockets or is not allowing long lasting connections.  The only way I know of to debug this from the outside (without knowing what the university is actually doing) is to run tons of experiments to find out what is and isn't blocked (trying different common ports, seeing exactly where in the webSocket communication the connection is droppped, etc...).

Answer (score 0):

Switching from HTTP to HTTPS should get around the problem with incompatible proxy server. That forces the proxy to use HTTP tunneling to maintain the connection instead performing whatever magic it does.